# Как добавить картинку в тэг option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, html-select

Я сделал такой переключатель языков:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lang = document.getElementById("lang");
  lang.onchange = function() {
    window.location =
      "https://studyintomsk.ru" +
      lang.options[lang.options.selectedIndex].value;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="lang" id="lang">
  <option value="/">Русский</option>
  <option class="eng" value="/en/main">English</option>
</select>
```

Код работает правильно, но есть одна проблема: в `option` нельзя добавлять картинки языков сбоку, а мне это нужно.

Как сверстать по-другому (с картинкой), но чтобы работало по такому же принципу (перекидывало на нужную страницу при выборе), на выбранной странице должен отображаться выбранный язык.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть вот такое решение https://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick для подобных задач,детализировано не вдавался как работает это штука,но по крайне мере уже она написана.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать [HTML Symbols](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp), или любые другие сторонние библиотеки иконок для того что бы добавить простую графику рядом и/или вместо текста:

```html
<select>
  <option>&#174; Copyrighted</option>
  <option>&reg; Registered</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Там нет флагов и вообще разноцветных символов по типу флагов. Там только чёрные символы так можно подставить

Comment: Про цвет в Вашем вопросе упоминания не было, флаги можно найти без проблем в библиотеках типа [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com), незнаю как сейчас, но раньше они поддерживали вставку через HTML Entity.

Comment: На счёт fa я как-то не подумал, спасибо